# QT5-alpha build errors in Ubuntu-Linux 11.10

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qt5

I tried the instructions of building latest QT5-Alpha(http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-Alpha
http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git)
 from GIT,but facing compilation in wayland files

Ubuntu Linux 11.10

```
__make[4]: Entering directory `/home/xyz/build/newqt5/qt5/qtwayland/src/plugins/platforms/wayland'
g++ -c -pipe -g -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -D_REENTRANT -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_NO_LIBUDEV -DQ_PLATFORM_WAYLAND -DQT_NO_WAYLAND_XKB -DQT_WAYLAND_GL_SUPPORT -DQT_WAYLAND_WINDOWMANAGER_SUPPORT -DQ_FONTCONFIGDATABASE -DQT_COMPILES_IN_HARFBUZZ -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/home/xyz/build/newqt5/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/home/xyz/build/newqt5/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.0.0 -I/home/xyz/build/newqt5/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.0.0/QtCore -I/home/xyz/build/newqt5/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore -I/home/xyz/build/newqt5/qt5/qtbase/include/QtGui/5.0.0 -I/home/xyz/build/newqt5/qt5/qtbase/include/QtGui/5.0.0/QtGui -I/home/xyz/build/newqt5/qt5/qtbase/include/QtGui -I/home/xyz/build/newqt5/qt5/qtbase/include/QtPlatformSupport/5.0.0 -I/home/xyz/build/newqt5/qt5/qtbase/include/QtPlatformSupport/5.0.0/QtPlatformSupport -I/home/xyz/build/newqt5/qt5/qtbase/include/QtPlatformSupport -I/home/xyz/build/newqt5/qt5/qtbase/include -I../../../shared -Igl_integration/xcomposite_share -I.moc/debug-shared -o .obj/debug-shared/qwaylandintegration.o qwaylandintegration.cpp
```

> **In file included from qwaylandshmwindow.h:45:0,
>                       from qwaylandintegration.cpp:46:
>       qwaylandwindow.h:112:18: error: ‘wl_callback_listener’ does not name a type**

```
make[4]: *** [.obj/debug-shared/qwaylandintegration.o] Error 1_
```

Any pointers to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the alpha source package here: http://releases.qt-project.org/qt5.0/alpha/ and use the steps in README file.

The master in git is NOT what was released as alpha. The build scripts are different. You have to wait for them to add alpha tag to pull it from git. But why not just grab the gz file?

Comment: it worked indeed thanks..thanks for pointing out the link for tar files rather than GIT :)